# Problems with converting column from object to float

Tags: python, pandas

After scraping the website, I have a column Price.

```
5        € 9.500,00
7        € 2.950,00
8        € 5.750,00
11      € 64.718,00
14       € 4.800,00
           ...     
3050     € 8.099,00
3051    € 12.500,00
3052    € 16.900,00
3054       € 699,00
3059     € 6.500,00
dtype: object
```

I have tried to drop Euro sign and convert it to float with a standard `str.replace.astype(float)` function, but it yielded mistakes.

I have found another possibility here with:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'')
df3['Price']=df3.Price.map(lambda x: locale.atof(x.strip('€')))
```

However, I have now a problem that dots now and prices are now incorrectly reflected for my further analysis:

```
5           9.500
7           2.950
8           5.750
11         64.718
14          4.800
          ...    
3050        8.099
3051       12.500
3052       16.900
3054    69900.000
3059        6.500
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the way you load the data supports a `thousands` and `decimal` option, for example Pandas `read_csv` does. You could also set the appropriate locale, like `de_DE` for example, but I personally don't like messing with locales as they're global state.

Personally I would solve this with a simple string replace:

```
df3['Price'] = df3.Price.map(lambda x: float(x.strip('€')
                                              .replace('.', '')
                                              .replace(',', '.')))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df['amount'] = df['amount'].str.replace(r'€|\.', '').str.replace(',', '.')
df['amount'] = df['amount'].astype(float)
print(df)

    amount
0   9500.0
1   2950.0
2   5750.0
3  64718.0
4   4800.0
5   8099.0
6  12500.0
7  16900.0
8    699.0
9   6500.0
```

Answer (score -1):

My naive answer is that you could multiply every value in your column by 1000 and solve your number issue.

So,

```
def fun(x):
   return x * 1000
df3['Price']=df3.Price.map(fun)
```

Comment: I must have misunderstood what your problem was.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it simply does not work in a disastrous manner. Check what will happen to `€ 699,00`.